# Vue how to split string by comma and save as array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a Ruby guy who is trying to get some Vue knowladge. In my projecy user can provide multiple `styleCodes` via input field - each of the styleCode is separated by a comma. I want to store this `styleCodes` in array to calculate its length freely. I've below:

```
<template>
  <form>
    <input type="text" v-model="tempStyleCodes">
  </form>
  <button
    type="button"
    @click="syncProducts"
  >
    Sync
  </button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'SyncProducts',
  data() {
    return {
      styleCodes: [],
      tempStyleCodes: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    productsToSyncAmount () {
      this.tempStyleCodes.split(',')
      this.styleCodes.push(this.tempStyleCodes)
      return this.styleCodes.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async syncProducts() {
      let confirmationText = `Do you want to ${this.productsToSyncAmount} sync products?`
      this.loadId = null

      if (this.productsToSyncAmount === 0) {
        ModalController.showToast('', 'Type product codes for sync first, please!', 'warning')
      }
      // (...) some ohter irrelevant code
    },
  }
}
```

I think I'll need something similar to Ruby method `.split(',')` because my code for sample input of `4321test, test, 908test` produces:

```
styleCodes: [ "4321test, test, 908test" ]
```

Where length will give me 1 element instead of 3.

So desired result should be:

```
styleCodes: [ "4321test", "test", "908test" ]
```

How to split these values?

Comment: String.split(' ').join(',')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are using the split function to check the length of the string i assume your issue isn't how to split the value but how to bind to it

in which case i suggest use a writable computed value

```
computed: {
  formattedStyleCodes :{
    get(){
      return this.styleCodes.join(",");
    },
    set(value){
      this.styleCodes= value.split(',');
    }
  }
},
```

you can then bind to it as

```
<input type="text" v-model="formattedStyleCodes ">
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: token, expected ","`

Comment: that means you are missing a comma, probably between elements in your object definitions

Comment: ah wait not that was me, typo'ed the one supposed to be between get and set

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String`'s [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method, which can take either a string or a regular expression as the separator.

```js
const codes = this.tempStyleCodes.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

Now that you have an array of codes, you can push all of them in `styleCodes` by using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (see [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/?search=spread%20operator)) which is accepted by `Array`'s [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method:

```js
this.styleCodes.push(...codes);
```

Example:

```js
const styleCodes = [];
const tempStyleCodes = "4321test, test, 908test";

const codes = tempStyleCodes.split(/\s*,\s*/);
styleCodes.push(...codes);

console.log(styleCodes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
watch: {
  tempStyleCodes(newVal){
     if(newVal) this.styleCodes =  newVal.split(',')
}
```